# Finding the intersection of two curves in a scatterplot (here: pvalues vs test-statistics)

Tags: r

i do

```
library(Hmisc)
df <- as.matrix(replicate(20, rnorm(20))) 
cor.df <- rcorr(df)
plot(cor.df$r,cor.df$P)
abline(h=0.05)
```

and i would like to know if R can compute the meeting point of the horizontal line and the bell-curve. Since i have a scatterplot, do i need to model the x,y-curve first, and then balance the two functions? Or can R do that graphically?
I actually want to know what the treshold for (uncorrected) pvalues indicating a significant test statistics for a given dataset would be. I am not a trained statistician, so excuse me if that is a basic question. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function to graphically calculate an intersection. There are functions like `uniroot` that you can use in R to find intersections, but you need to have proper functions and have a good idea of the interval where the intersection occurs.

It would be best to properly model the curve in question, but a simply way to approximate a function when you have a bunch of points on the curve is just to use linear interpolation between the observed points. You can create a function for your points with `approxfun`

```
f1 <- approxfun(cor.df$r,cor.df$P, rule=2)
```

(again, a proper model would be better, but just for the sake of example, i'll continue with this function).

Now we can find the place where this curve cross 0.05 with

```
uniroot(function(x) f1(x)-.05, c(-1,-.001))$root
# [1] -0.4437796
uniroot(function(x) f1(x)-.05, c(.001, 1))$root
# [1] 0.4440005
```